# How to add CProgressCtrl to a CListCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc, drawing, clistctrl

I'm looking to add a progress bar to an index in a list control. I know there isn't a simple command to do this and requires a type of drawing but I can't find any good explanations on how to go about accomplishing this. I have a mediocre understanding of MFC so this might be a little advanced but I was hoping someone could give me a good example of how to do  this or point me to a link that explains something similar to this.

Comment: removed c++-cli tag and added c++ tag

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear - do you want a single `CProgressCtrl` for a `CListCtrl` or multiple ones?

Regardless, you may find this article from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6813/List-Control-Extended-for-Progress-Control) of interest, as it includes a ready-made control. No guarantees on the quality of the control, but it should at least get you started.

Comment: Ultimately I would like to have multiple but I was looking to learn how to just add one and then go from there. But thanks for the link I'll give it a look.